# Responsive image with flex wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want responsive image size with flex wrap. What i want is wrap after min-width of image has been reached, but what happens is it wraps image with max-width instead. First container without `flex-direction` and second with `flex-direction: wrap`.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container, .container-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-width: 250px;
}

.item-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <img class="item-image" src="https://picsum.photos/300"/>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="item-image" src="https://picsum.photos/300"/>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="item-image" src="https://picsum.photos/300"/>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="item-image" src="https://picsum.photos/300"/>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-wrap">
  <div class="item">
    <img class="item-image" src="https://picsum.photos/300"/>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="item-image" src="https://picsum.photos/300"/>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="item-image" src="https://picsum.photos/300"/>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="item-image" src="https://picsum.photos/300"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you exactly want, can't fully get it :)

Comment: i want to combine both results, so items should be getting smaller first to a point when they reach their min-width, and then wrap. Instead it either scales items but no wraps (when no flex-wrap) and it wraps immedietly my items without scalling them first when flex-wrap: wrap

Comment: Do we want same behaviour for all the 8 items? What I understand is first all the images should shrink responsively to 100px width and then start to wrap. Right?

Comment: yeah thats correct

Comment: Sure :) Let me give it a try. Can I use CSS-Grid ?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. But try setting `flex: 1` for `.item` and remove `max-width: 250px` from that same class. You get the result you want?

Comment: css grid is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code for all scenarios:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 2px;
}

.item-image {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="item">
        <img class="item-image" src="https://picsum.photos/300" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="item-image" src="https://picsum.photos/300" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="item-image" src="https://picsum.photos/300" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="item-image" src="https://picsum.photos/300" />
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img class="item-image" src="https://picsum.photos/300" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="item-image" src="https://picsum.photos/300" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="item-image" src="https://picsum.photos/300" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="item-image" src="https://picsum.photos/300" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Fake: Have used the more precise scenarios (real time scenario) in my code. Hope this helps. If so do  rate and accept the answer :) So that others can also benefit. Thanks. you may need to do small tweeks as per your requirement though !

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use a media query?

```
@media(max-width:150px){ 
   .item, .container-wrap{
        display:block;
        flex:none;
   } 
}
```